# How do you check the linearity of a multiple regression

Tags: multiple-regression

With Univariate regression it's very easy to see if the correlation is linear or otherwise, but in a multiple regression things can look very complicated, polynomial or other correlations can be hidden by the interaction of of the variables. I understand that you can use power terms in the variables but the relationship to the dependent variable should still be linear. How do  I know if multiple regression is appropriate?

Comment: Most common way to check linearity is to scatter-plot residuals (studentized preferably) against the linearly predicted values. Curved or non-horizontally spead cloud on such a plot is diagnostic for non-linearity. To uncover more hidden (partial) non-linearity plot the residuals against each of the predictors.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed the most common and easy way would be to use scatter plot of residual versus predicted value; a horizontal band of points indicates a linear relationship.