# Validity of the linearity assumption

Tags: multiple-regression, least-squares, linear, assumptions

I have to research unaided recall of commercials given a set of variables. So, I formulated the following model:

$unaided = \beta_0 + \beta_1duration + \beta_2blocksize + \beta_3position + \beta_4 position^2 + \beta_5primacy + \beta_6recency + \varepsilon$

$unaided$ is the proportion of people (out of 200 people) that recalled a commercial.

$primacy$ and $recency$ are binary variables.

Now I needed to check the OLS assumptions and verify if OLS is the right choice, and I'm a bit confused if the linearity assumption holds or not?

I know that my model is linear in  $\beta$ and not linear in $x$. So, do I just assume that it holds by construction? or do I need to prove it, if so, how do I prove it?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the linearity assumption with a plot [of observed versus predicted values or a plot of residuals versus predicted values](http://people.duke.edu/~rnau/testing.htm#linearity). If the plot indicates a nonlinear trend you can transform the dependent or he independent variables. This is something that you actually have done anyway, since you added a quadratic version of position. So you can see if the mentioned plots show you some nonlinear pattern (observed/ predicted: should be approximately a straight line with 45% degree; residuals/ predicted: should be approximately a horizontal line). In R this can be done easily, see [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/39-regression-model-diagnostics/161-linear-regression-assumptions-and-diagnostics-in-r-essentials/).

Also always keep in mind to firstly look for answers on stackexchange. There are [many](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Linearity+regression) questions on linearity and [some](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70009/how-do-you-check-the-linearity-of-a-multiple-regression&ved=2ahUKEwjQjbz9xPDhAhXhMewKHRGyAe8QjjgwC3oECAQQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2G014RzS2u2Qie8Z9nLlcs&cshid=1556377280352) of them answer your question.