# Detecting Non-linearity in large data sets

Tags: regression, residuals, large-data, diagnostic, exploratory-data-analysis

I understand that the best way to test for non-linearity is to look at the residual plots. However, I have 20,000 or more points and any pattern in the residuals is not easy to spot. Are there approaches other than eyeing the residuals to test for non-linearity in regression. Note that I work in an area where there is little statistical analysis, so there is no theory to build on.

I asked something like this before, but the answer given, to use the residuals won't really work given the shear number of points. So I am looking for the best test, or a way to change the residuals to address this issue. [Is there formal test of non-linearity in linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/405961/is-there-formal-test-of-non-linearity-in-linear-regression)

Comment: One usually employs robust smooths of the residuals as a start.  With such tools it's possible to identify patterns in millions of residuals.  It sounds like you don't need or want a formal test: you need methods of *exploratory data analysis.* There is a lot of literature on that, starting with the methods shown in regression textbooks.

Comment: thanks whuber. I am not familiar with the robust smooths you mention. Can you suggest a source for this. My primary concern, given a total lack of theory, is to show what the impact of various variables are. My concern with non-linearity (given that I have the whole population) is how it changes the coefficients. Because those I work for are very concerned about which variables are  important. I have limited expertise in non-linear data and most that I have looked at don't generate coefficients (I have problems understanding if a loess for example indicates a variable is important or not).

Comment: This is such a huge set of issues to deal with I couldn't even begin addressing them in the small space allowed for comments.  Search our site for upvoted posts on *Exploratory Data Analysis,* *regression diagnostics,* *residuals*, and *model selection,* then go on from there.

Comment: thanks very much. I actually have done this a lot, non-linearity continues to cause problems for me.